# Snowflake - I want to create a log table of filenames I have loaded from S3

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We load several files a day for one table from S3 into Snowflake.  I want to know how I can create a permanent log table of the filename, no of rows, successful/unsuccessful load etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snowflake already maintains this info for you in a view called [load_history](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/load_history.html). If you want to put this into a table you could insert into with this select:

```sql
select * from snowflake.ACCOUNT_USAGE.LOAD_HISTORY
```

Comment: Perfect thanks :)  Knew there must be something somewhere but obviously wasn't asking the correct question.